# select a new column with group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to select one other column with group by clause with sum or count functions.

```
SELECT t1.[09to12PM], t2.[12to15PM], t3.[15to17PM], t4.[17to23PM]
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT (Premark) AS [09to12PM]
   FROM saree_order_stages
   WHERE Premark LIKE '%ready to go%' AND Premark != 'not ready to go'
     AND pdate>='2016-03-29 09:00:00' AND Pdate <='2016-03-29 12:00:00') t1,

  (SELECT COUNT (Premark) AS [12to15PM]
   FROM saree_order_stages
   WHERE Premark LIKE '%ready to go%' AND Premark != 'not ready to go'
     AND pdate>='2016-03-29 12:00:00' AND Pdate <='2016-03-29 15:00:00') t2,

  (SELECT COUNT (Premark) AS [15to17PM]
   FROM saree_order_stages
   WHERE Premark LIKE '%ready to go%' AND Premark != 'not ready to go'
     AND pdate>='2016-03-29 15:00:00' AND Pdate <='2016-03-29 17:00:00') t3,

  (SELECT COUNT (Premark) AS [17to23PM]
   FROM saree_order_stages
   WHERE Premark LIKE '%ready to go%' AND Premark != 'not ready to go'
     AND pdate>='2016-03-29 17:00:00' AND Pdate <='2016-03-29 23:00:00') t4
GROUP BY t1.[09to12PM], t2.[12to15PM], t3.[15to17PM], t4.[17to23PM]
```

here is result is showing this

```
09to12PM  12to15PM 15to17PM 17to23PM
23         21        15        19
```

**we want** to add one column name just like this.
and showing data as follows.

```
name 09to12PM  12to15PM 15to17PM 17to23PM
amit   23         21        15        19 
sumit  11         22        11        45
raj    14         4         5         67
```

Comment: from where the `name` will come?

Comment: is a part of table fields and should be come 1st column as per table dispaly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your query using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    name,
    [09to12PM] = SUM(CASE WHEN pdate>='2016-03-29 09:00:00' AND Pdate <='2016-03-29 12:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [12to15PM] = SUM(CASE WHEN pdate>='2016-03-29 12:00:00' AND Pdate <='2016-03-29 15:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [15to17PM] = SUM(CASE WHEN pdate>='2016-03-29 15:00:00' AND Pdate <='2016-03-29 17:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [17to23PM] = SUM(CASE WHEN pdate>='2016-03-29 17:00:00' AND Pdate <='2016-03-29 23:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM saree_order_stages
WHERE
    Premark LIKE '%ready to go%'
    AND Premark != 'not ready to go'
    AND CAST(pdate AS DATE) = '2016-03-29'
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)